# filter by tag in review is not working

Tags: bug, stack-overflow, tags, review, vote-to-close

I click on [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review) in StackOverflow, and its open review page.

Then I clicked on [java](/questions/tagged/java) in `by tag:` filter in [Close Vote](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close) section. Now I want to change filter from [java](/questions/tagged/java) to [python](/questions/tagged/python), when I change in url `?filter-tags=java` to `?filter-tags=python`, its still showing me [java](/questions/tagged/java) questions.

Comment: That's most likely because you have a custom filter that isn't being "overwritten". Still a bug of course, but if you clear the custom tag filter you can use the URL filter.

Comment: I got the patch, when I click on [tag:java] its convert url to http://stackoverflow.com/review/close/5744761?filter-tags=java where `5744761` is might be ID of question. When I change it to http://stackoverflow.com/review/close/5744761?filter-tags=python it shows `5744761` only.

Comment: OMG, so simple. This is the ID of the review item, yes. Please write this as an answer, as others are likely to fall into it as well. :)

Comment: I dont think I can give answer to my own question, or I dont have privilege for that. Please can you write answer?

Comment: Of course you can, just confirm the dialog that appears when you click the Answer button. It's totally legit. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URL is using **ID of review item**, so when clicking on [java](/questions/tagged/java) it convert url to https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/5744761?filter-tags=java where `5744761` is ID.

When I manually change the url to https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/5744761?filter-tags=python it is still in the same item, that's why the tags do not change.

However, when completing the review of this item (taking any action) the next item will be loaded with the tag filter set in the URL.